# Change backgroundcolour of input after onblur automatically across page

Tags: javascript, onblur

I would like an input field to have the background colour changed after onblur. Automatically for all fields on every page. So I am hoping for a script in the header that will automatically affect all input fields.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('blur',function(){
        //anything here. Notice that both this and element refer to each input element.
    })
  });
}
```

document.querySelectorAll or any function returning a NodeList object can be used.

Comment: this one works, but how can I includes textarea and select as well please? and checkboxes?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('input,textarea,select')

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be done. Because you've demonstrated no attempt, I'm choosing to assume you're willing to support the latest/up-to-date browsers (rather than all legacy browsers):

```
function colorOnBlur(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', colorOnBlur);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AwFS3/).

Or you can add a new class-name to the elements (rather than changing the `style` object yourself:

```
function colorOnBlur(){
    this.classList.add('blurred');
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', colorOnBlur);
}
```

Coupled with the CSS:

```
input.blurred {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AwFS3/1/).

Obviously, adjust the relevant colours to your own tastes/requirements.

References:

- [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: thank you so much. How do I do this for textarea and select as well?

Answer (score 0):

since you start up in an "onblur" state, you should listen to the focus/click event, not the blur event

add css

```
input{ /*Blurred state*/
    background-color: red;
}
.onFocus input{ /*clicked state*/
    background-color: green;
}
```

add some javascript

```
$(input).
    click(function(e){
        body.className="onFocus";
    }).
    blur(function(){
        body.className="";
    });
```

Comment: I didn't see [tag:jquery] in the question, did you? Was it edited out or something..?

Comment: no, but I made the assumption, that a person asking such a question will !need! to be using jquery, zepto or similar. But you are correct, he asked for javascript and I'm a schmuck ;)